# Show that no values of $b$ can make the equation $b\sin(bx)-2\cos(bx) = 0$ true.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to prove that $()=\cos()$ is a solution to the DE $'''+2''+'+2=0$, and by substituting $f$
and its derivatives, I have simplified the equation to $$(^2−1)(\sin()−2\cos())=0.$$ It is easy to show $^2−1=0$ has appropriate values for $b$
, but I am not so sure about
$b\sin(bx)−2\cos(bx)=0$.

If I have the equation $b\sin(bx)-2\cos(bx) = 0$, how do I prove that no values of $b \in \mathbb{R}$, can make the equation true? It it enough to say that $2\cot(bx) \neq b$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, hence $b$ does not exists?

Comment: This statement is false. The only value of $b$ where this happens is $b = 0$.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): what is your real question?

Comment: @TobyMak I am trying to prove that $f(x) = \cos(bx)$ is a solution to the DE $y'''+ 2y'' + y' +2y = 0$, and by substituting $f$ and its derivatives, I have simplified the equation to $(b^2-1)(b\sin(bx)-2\cos(bx))=0$. It is easy to show $b^2 -1 = 0$ has appropriate values for $b$, but I am not so sure about $b\sin(bx) - 2\cos(bx) = 0$.

Comment: That sounds much better, so thank you for adding this information. If you could copy that into the question body, I'll remove the downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to justify it.

When $x=0$, we have $-2=0$ regardless of the value of $b$, hence no such $b$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Here it is an alternative way to approach it for the sake of curiosity.

You can actually solve the proposed ODE:

\begin{align*}
y''' + 2y'' + y' + 2y = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow (y''' + 2y'') + (y' + 2y) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (y' + 2y)'' + (y' + 2y) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow u'' + u = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow u(x) = c_{1}\cos(x) + c_{2}\sin(x)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y' + 2y = c_{1}\cos(x) + c_{2}\sin(x)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\exp(2x)y)' = \exp(2x)(c_{1}\cos(x) + c_{2}\sin(x))
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

$$(^2−1)(\sin()−2\cos())=0.$$
$$(\sin()−2\cos())=0.$$
$$\implies \tan (bx)=\dfrac  2b \,\, (\forall \,\, x) $$
Can't be true since $x$ is variable and $\dfrac 2b $ is a constant. It can only be true for a certain value of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

$\cos bx$ is not a solution, as after differentiating once, you will get $-b \sin bx$, and the only value of $b$ that will cancel the $\sin$ terms is $0$. You might then try $A \cos bx + B \cos bx$, but there is a much simpler way.

Find the characteristic polynomial by substituting in $y = e^{ax}$:

$$r^3 + 2r^2 + r + 2 = 0 \Rightarrow r^2(r+2) + (r+2) = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow (r^2+1)(r+2) = 0, r = -2, ±i$$

and since $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ can be expressed as linear combinations of $e^{ix}, e^{-ix}$, the particular solution is $y = c_1e^{-2x} + c_2 \cos x + c_3 \sin x$.